# How to getPosition of the Item recyclerview with DataBinding?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, android-livedata

I make a list of Item using Recycler, before I use databinding I can get the position simply by call `modelitem.getposition(1).likecounter`
Right now when I use `databinding modelitem.likecounter.getValue()`
my `RecyclerView` become weird and all item became same Value, because I can't get the position

MainActivity.java

```
public void createDummyData1UPDATE(int ReceivedDummyUrutan, int ReceivedTotalThread, String ReceivedDummyIDContent, String ReceivedDummyTitle, String ReceivedDummyPublishTime, String ReceivedDummyImageOri, String ReceivedDummyShortDescription, int ReceivedDummySeen, int ReceivedDummyComment, int ReceivedDummyLike, int ReceivedDummyisComment, int ReceivedDummyisLike, int ReceivedDummyisBookmark) {
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(ReceivedDummyIDContent, ReceivedDummyPublishTime, ReceivedDummyImageOri, ReceivedDummyShortDescription, ReceivedDummySeen, ReceivedDummyComment, ReceivedDummyisComment, ReceivedDummyisBookmark,"x53535", "No Error"));



    if(ReceivedDummyUrutan ==  ReceivedTotalThread-1){

        modelSingleHotTrendingNewsBB.gametitle.setValue(ReceivedDummyTitle);
        modelSingleHotTrendingNewsBB.likecounter.setValue(ReceivedDummyLike);
        modelSingleHotTrendingNewsBB.islike.setValue(ReceivedDummyisLike);

        //LISTENER
        listenerHotTrendingNews = new AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews.RecyclerViewClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRowHotTrendingNewsContainerClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Kamu Ngeclick Row Games News " + modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getIdcontent(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //Passing Data to TabDetailHotActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TabDetailHotActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("DummyIDContentPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getIdcontent());
                /*intent.putExtra("DummyTitlePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGametitle());*/
                intent.putExtra("DummyPublishTimePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedate());
                intent.putExtra("DummyImageOriPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGameimage());
                intent.putExtra("DummyShortDescriptionPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedescription());
                intent.putExtra("DummySeenPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getSeencounter());
                intent.putExtra("DummyCommentPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getCommentcounter());
                /*intent.putExtra("DummyLikePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getLikecounter());*/
                intent.putExtra("DummyisCommentPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getIscomment());
                /*intent.putExtra("DummyisLikePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getIslike());*/
                intent.putExtra("DummyisBookmarkPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getTrendingnewssaving());

                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRowCommentViewClick(View view, int position) {
                /*mainActivity_.rncryptorCommentLikeBookmark("isComment", modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getIdcontent(), modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getIscomment());*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onRowLikeViewClick(View view, int position) {

                if(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsBB.islike != null) {
                    mainActivity_.rncryptorCommentLikeBookmark("isLike", modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getIdcontent(), modelSingleHotTrendingNewsBB.islike.getValue());
                }

            }
        };

        //RECYCLERVIEW
        ModelSectionHotTrendingNews modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX = new ModelSectionHotTrendingNews();
        modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.setHeaderTitle("TRENDING NEWS");
        modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.setAllItemsInSection(modelSingleHotTrendingNews);
        modelSectionHotTrendingNews.add(modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX);

        /*RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews = v.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView_Single_HotTrendingNews);*/
        RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews = fragmentTabhotBinding.RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews;
        RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapterSectionHotTrendingNews = new AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews(getActivity(), modelSectionHotTrendingNews, listenerHotTrendingNews);
        RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setAdapter(adapterSectionHotTrendingNews);
        //Optimized
        RecyclerViewSingleHotLatestNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerViewSingleHotLatestNews.setItemViewCacheSize(20);

        /*ModelSingleHotTrendingNews modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX;
        modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX = modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(0);
        fragmentTabhotBinding.setRfg(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX);*/
        ViewModel_HotTrendingNews viewModel_hotTrendingNews;
        viewModel_hotTrendingNews = null;
        fragmentTabhotBinding.setApaan(viewModel_hotTrendingNews);


    }


}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public void getisCommentLikeBookmarkMainActivity(int ReceivedDummyLike, int ReceivedDummyisLike){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "BerhasilLikeUnlike="+ReceivedDummyLike+"DummyisLike"+ ReceivedDummyisLike, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    modelSingleHotTrendingNewsBB.gametitle.observe(getActivity(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String s) {
            fragmentTabhotBinding.testes.setText(s);
        }
    });


    modelSingleHotTrendingNewsBB.gametitle.postValue("Title Baru");
    modelSingleHotTrendingNewsBB.likecounter.postValue(ReceivedDummyLike);
    modelSingleHotTrendingNewsBB.islike.postValue(ReceivedDummyisLike);

    /*modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.gametitle.observe(this, new Observer<List<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews) {
            adapterSingleHotTrendingNews.setmodelSingleHotTrendingNewsSD((ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews>) modelSingleHotTrendingNews);
        }
    });*/

    ViewModel_HotTrendingNews viewModel_hotTrendingNews = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(ViewModel_HotTrendingNews.class);
    viewModel_hotTrendingNews.TopTitle.postValue("YAHYAHYAH");
    viewModel_hotTrendingNews.TopTitle.observe(getActivity(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String s) {
            fragmentTabhotBinding.testes.setText(s);
        }
    });


}
```

Model.java

```java
public class ModelSingleHotTrendingNews extends ViewModel implements Serializable {

    private String idcontent;
    public MutableLiveData<String> gametitle = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private String gamedate;
    private String gameimage;
    private String gamedescription;

    private int seencounter;
    private int commentcounter;
    public MutableLiveData<Integer> likecounter = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private int iscomment;
    public MutableLiveData<Integer> islike = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private int trendingnewssaving;

    private String value;
    private String message;



    public ModelSingleHotTrendingNews() {
    }

    public ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(MutableLiveData<String> gametitle) {
        this.gametitle = gametitle;
    }

    public ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(String idcontent, String gamedate, String gameimage, String gamedescription, int seencounter, int commentcounter, int iscomment, int trendingnewssaving, String value, String message) {
        this.idcontent = idcontent;
        this.gamedate = gamedate;
        this.gameimage = gameimage;
        this.gamedescription = gamedescription;
        this.seencounter = seencounter;
        this.commentcounter = commentcounter;
        this.iscomment = iscomment;
        this.trendingnewssaving = trendingnewssaving;
        this.value = value;
        this.message = message;
    }


    public MutableLiveData<String> getGametitle() {
        gametitle.setValue(gametitle.getValue());
        return gametitle;
    }

    public void setGametitle(MutableLiveData<String> gametitle) {
        this.gametitle = gametitle;
    }


    public MutableLiveData<Integer> getLikecounter() {
        likecounter.setValue(likecounter.getValue());
        return likecounter;
    }

    public void setlikecounter(MutableLiveData<Integer> likecounter) {
        this.likecounter = likecounter;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> getIslike() {
        if(islike.getValue() == null) {
            islike.setValue(0);
        }
        return islike;
    }

    public void setIslike(MutableLiveData<Integer> islike) {
        this.islike = islike;
    }


    public String getIdcontent() {
        return idcontent;
    }

    public void setIdcontent(String idcontent) {
        this.idcontent = idcontent;
    }




    public String getGamedate() {
        return gamedate;
    }

    public void setGamedate(String gamedate) {
        this.gamedate = gamedate;
    }

    public String getGameimage() {
        return gameimage;
    }

    public void setGameimage(String gameimage) {
        this.gameimage = gameimage;
    }

    public String getGamedescription() {
        return gamedescription;
    }

    public void setGamedescription(String gamedescription) {
        this.gamedescription = gamedescription;
    }

    public int getSeencounter() {
        return seencounter;
    }

    public void setSeencounter(int seencounter) {
        this.seencounter = seencounter;
    }

    public int getCommentcounter() {
        return commentcounter;
    }

    public void setCommentcounter(int commentcounter) {
        this.commentcounter = commentcounter;
    }



    public int getIscomment() {
        return iscomment;
    }

    public void setIscomment(int iscomment) {
        this.iscomment = iscomment;
    }



    public int getTrendingnewssaving() {
        return trendingnewssaving;
    }

    public void setTrendingnewssaving(int trendingnewssaving) {
        this.trendingnewssaving = trendingnewssaving;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

UPDATED//Adapter.java

```java
public class AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews;

    private RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;


    public AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews(Context mContext, ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews, RecyclerViewClickListener mListener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.modelSingleHotTrendingNews = modelSingleHotTrendingNews;
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }




    public void setmodelSingleHotTrendingNewsSD(ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews) {
        this.modelSingleHotTrendingNews = modelSingleHotTrendingNews;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    //Container
    @Override
    public SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        /*View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_single_hottrendingnews, null);
        return new SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(v, mListener);*/


        View v;
        /*ModelSingleHotTrendingNews modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX;
            modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX = modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(0);
            fragmentTabhotBinding.setRfg(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX);*/
        final ItemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding itemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding;
        itemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()),
                R.layout.item_single_hottrendingnews, viewGroup, false);
        itemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding.setLifecycleOwner((FragmentActivity) mContext);

        final ModelSingleHotTrendingNews modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX;
        modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX = new ViewModelProvider((FragmentActivity) mContext).get(ModelSingleHotTrendingNews.class);
        modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.gametitle.observe((FragmentActivity) mContext, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String s) {
                itemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding.TVGameTitle.setText(s);
            }
        });
        modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.likecounter.observe((FragmentActivity) mContext, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
                itemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding.TVLikeCounter.setText(String.valueOf(integer));
            }
        });
        modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.islike.observe((FragmentActivity) mContext, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
                if(integer == 0){
                    itemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding.IMGLikeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_off);
                }else if(integer == 1){
                    itemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding.IMGLikeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_on);
                }
            }
        });


        return new SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(itemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding, mListener);
    }


    //Fill Container with Model Setter Getter
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder = (SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder) holder;
        final ModelSingleHotTrendingNews modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX = modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position);


        //SETBINDING
        ModelSingleHotTrendingNews modelSingleHotTrendingNewsZ;
        modelSingleHotTrendingNewsZ = new ViewModelProvider((FragmentActivity) mContext).get(ModelSingleHotTrendingNews.class);

        //Set
        singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVGameDate.setText(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGamedate());
        /*singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVGameTitle.setText(singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.modelSingleHotTrendingNewsZ.gametitle.getValue());*/
        Glide.with(mContext).load(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGameimage()).into(singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGGameImage);
        /*singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGGameImage.setImageResource(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGameimage());*/

        singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVSeenCounter.setText(String.valueOf(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getSeencounter()));
        singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVCommentCounter.setText(String.valueOf(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getCommentcounter()));
        /*singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVLikeCounter.setText(String.valueOf(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsZ.likecounter.getValue()));*/

        if (modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getIscomment() == 0) {
            singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGCommentView.setImageResource(R.drawable.comment_off);
        } else if (modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getIscomment() == 1) {
            singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGCommentView.setImageResource(R.drawable.comment_on);
        }

        /*if (modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.islike.getValue() != null){
            if (modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.islike.getValue().equals(0)) {
                singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGLikeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_off);
            } else if (modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.islike.getValue().equals(1)) {
                singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGLikeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_on);
            }
        }*/

        if(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getTrendingnewssaving() == 0) {
            singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_off);
            singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else if(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getTrendingnewssaving() == 1) {
            singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_on);
        }

        singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final int booltrendingnewssaving = modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getTrendingnewssaving();

                final String idcontent = modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getIdcontent();

                if (booltrendingnewssaving == 1){
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn Off Saved News " + idcontent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_off);
                    modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.setTrendingnewssaving(0);
                    /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, false);*/
                } else if(booltrendingnewssaving == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn On Saved News " + idcontent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_on);
                    modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.setTrendingnewssaving(1);
                    /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, true);*/
                }
            }
        });



       /* Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.bg)
                .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/

        /*singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedescription(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //Passing Data to GameDescriptionActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GameDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ImagePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGameimage());
                intent.putExtra("NamePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedate());
                intent.putExtra("UrlPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getIdcontent());
                intent.putExtra("DescriptionPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGametitle());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int itemCount = modelSingleHotTrendingNews.size();
        return itemCount;
    }

    public void setmodelSingleHotTrendingNews(ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews) {
        this.modelSingleHotTrendingNews = modelSingleHotTrendingNews;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView TVGameDate;
        TextView TVGameTitle;
        ImageView IMGGameImage;

        TextView TVSeenCounter;
        TextView TVCommentCounter;
        TextView TVLikeCounter;

        ImageView IMGSeenView;
        ImageView IMGCommentView;
        ImageView IMGLikeView;

        ImageView ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving;
        private RelativeLayout ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer;

        private RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;

        //
        private ItemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding itemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding;
        ModelSingleHotTrendingNews modelSingleHotTrendingNewsZ;


        public SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(ItemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding itemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding, RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
            super(itemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding.getRoot());

            this.itemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding = itemSingleHottrendingnewsBinding;

            TVGameDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_GameDate);
            TVGameTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_GameTitle);
            IMGGameImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_GameImage);

            TVSeenCounter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_SeenCounter);
            TVCommentCounter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_CommentCounter);
            TVLikeCounter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_LikeCounter);

            IMGSeenView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_SeenView);
            IMGCommentView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_CommentView);
            IMGLikeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_LikeView);

            ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ICON_HotTrendingNewsSaving);
            ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ROW_HotTrendingNewsContainer);

            mListener = listener;
            ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer.setOnClickListener(this);
            IMGCommentView.setOnClickListener(this);
            IMGLikeView.setOnClickListener(this);

            //
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.ROW_HotTrendingNewsContainer:
                    mListener.onRowHotTrendingNewsContainerClick(ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer, getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
                case R.id.IMG_CommentView:
                    mListener.onRowCommentViewClick(IMGCommentView, getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
                case R.id.IMG_LikeView:
                    mListener.onRowLikeViewClick(IMGLikeView, getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
        void onRowHotTrendingNewsContainerClick(View view, int position);
        void onRowCommentViewClick(View view, int position);
        void onRowLikeViewClick(View view, int position);
    }

}
```

item_single_hottrendingnews.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="ohyeah"
            type="com.indofun.android.indojoy.models.model_hottrendingnews.ModelSingleHotTrendingNews" />
        <variable
            name="position"
            type="int"/>
    </data>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ROW_HotTrendingNewsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RL_MainScreen"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/darkgrey"
                android:padding="0dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IMG_GameImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:padding="4dp" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TV_GameDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/IMG_GameImage"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="13.3 Inch, 256 GB"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TV_GameTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/TV_GameDate"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:text="@{ohyeah.gametitle}"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IMG_SeenView"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/TV_GameTitle"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/watch" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TV_SeenCounter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/TV_GameTitle"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/IMG_SeenView"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/small_intrinsic_padding"
                    android:paddingTop="1dp"
                    android:text="999"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Second.Light"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IMG_CommentView"
                    android:layout_width="8dp"
                    android:layout_height="8dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/TV_GameTitle"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TV_SeenCounter"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/comment_off" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TV_CommentCounter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/TV_GameTitle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/IMG_CommentView"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/small_intrinsic_padding"
                    android:text="999"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Second.Light"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IMG_LikeView"
                    android:layout_width="8dp"
                    android:layout_height="8dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/TV_GameTitle"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TV_CommentCounter"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/heart_off" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TV_LikeCounter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/TV_GameTitle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/IMG_LikeView"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/small_intrinsic_padding"
                    android:text="@{String.valueOf(ohyeah.likecounter)}"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Second.Light"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />


            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: `itemPosition` of `ViewHolder` is passed parameter in `onBindViewHolder`.But, your code about implementation `RecyclerView`, `ViewDataBinding` incorrectly. Show your `item_single_hottrendingnews` xml.

Comment: also, check this [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-data-binding-recyclerview-db7c40d9f0e4).

Comment: @EthanChoi I Updated the xml in my post